# Laravel Eloquent Search Multiple Words from Different Fields

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I currently have the following code which is working...

```
$searchString = $request->searchstring;
$searchValues = preg_split('/\s+/', $searchString, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$cards=Card::where(function ($q) use ($searchValues){
    foreach($searchValues as $value){
        $q->orWhere('firstname', 'like', "%{$value}%");
        $q->orWhere('lastname', 'like', "%{$value}%");
        $q->orWhere('cardset', 'like', "%{$value}%");
    }
})->paginate(24);
```

It is producing the following sql when I do a dd...

```
select * from "cards" where ("firstname" like ? or "lastname" like ? or "cardset" like ? or "firstname" like ? or "lastname" like ? or "cardset" like ?)
```

but the sql I would like should be...

```
select * from "cards" where ("firstname" like ? or "lastname" like ? or "cardset" like ?) AND ("firstname" like ? or "lastname" like ? or "cardset" like ?)
```

I've tried a couple of things but can't seem to get it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the following sql query

```
select * from "cards" where ("firstname" like ? or "lastname" like ? or "cardset" like ?) AND ("firstname" like ? or "lastname" like ? or "cardset" like ?)
```

Try this..

```
$cards = Card::Query();

foreach($searchValues as $value)
{
    $cards = $cards->where(function ($q) use ($value) {
                    $q->orWhere('firstname', 'like', "%{$value}%");
                    $q->orWhere('lastname', 'like', "%{$value}%");
                    $q->orWhere('cardset', 'like', "%{$value}%");
                });
}

$cards = $cards->paginate(24);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$cards = Card::where(function ($q) use ($searchValues) {
    foreach ($searchValues as $value) {
        $q->where(function($q) use ($value) {
            $q->orWhere('firstname', 'like', "%{$value}%");
            $q->orWhere('lastname', 'like', "%{$value}%");
            $q->orWhere('cardset', 'like', "%{$value}%");
        });
    }
})
```

It produces:

```
select * from `cards` where ((`firstname` like ? or `lastname` like ? or `cardset` like ?) and (`firstname` like ? or `lastname` like ? or `cardset` like ?) and (`firstname` like ? or `lastname` like ? or `cardset` like ?))
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Laravel 10.47, there are new methods that simplify this:

```
whereAny
whereAll
```

The above code can now be:

```
$cards = Card::whereAny(['firstname','lastname','cardset'], 'LIKE', "%$value%");
```

[Laravel Docs - Where Any / All Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/queries#where-any-all-clauses)